# this.props errors with a function with axios

Tags: javascript

look i have this error Uncaught TypeError:

Comment: not an answer, but FYI: `var thisObj` is not required in `handleSubmit(event) {` - everywhere you've used `thisObj` can just as easily be `this`

Comment: Where are you importing `createUser` function? Can post details of imports as well?

Comment: What happened to the contents of this question?